# How can I display a formula in TextView

Tags: android, textview

[image: how can i display such string in TextView]

How can I display such a string in a `TextView`.

I tried a lot but cant find the solution.
I can't display the base value `CHA2DS2-VASc`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest you to create HTML string for this formula and display it inside the TextView by using:

```
String formulaString = "<body>CHA<sub>2</sub>DS<sub>2</sub>-VAS<sub>c</sub></body>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(formulaString));
```

Comment: is there any way that i can do it in layoutXML