# How to show special characters in Android?

Tags: java, android, special-characters, android-source

I am developing a native app which consists of some mathematical formulas.

Formulas will be like.........

[image: Formulas]

I want to display such formulas in my application, but i don't how to use these special characters in Android. I want to display each formula individually in a list view......  If i am copying formula & if i am setting text to text view means it is showing like

```
   txtv.setText("\\cos^2\\theta + \\sin^2\\theta = 1\\! ");
```

and getting output in the same pattern.  So, can anyone help me how to use these mathematical special characters in Android..

Comment: check: [how can i display formula in TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11446426/379693)

Comment: @PareshMayani Your solution is good but how to covert square roots, theta values as per my above picture with your code... can you please convert one & post the answer. thanks....

Comment: sorry dear, i am weak in Mathematics.

Comment: How about rather displaying special characters in a image than a textview?

Comment: @Luke Taylor means need to get all the images of special characters & need to display them in imageview.. Is it the thing you are saying....

Comment: Yes, or you could do this via a surfaceview.

Comment: how can we use surfaceview. nt having any idea regarding that.....

Comment: This might be helpful to someone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777558/full-latex-parser-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, there are not a lot of different solutions.. 
There are no 'magical answer", here are some different ways to achieve what you want.

1) Using a webview with some Javascript

2) using a server to produce a picture of the formula.

3) Using a 9.png file embededd in your app with the square root symbol and display it as textview background

4) Drawing a canvas with all your text and symbols

5) using Hexadecimal code: http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/symbols.html

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/mathchart.html

6) Maybe other ideas, but definitely no way to achieve a 300 formula listview in a easiest way.

Answer (score 2):

This one seem quite good and works in Android without any issue: http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html

Edit:
You can run this inside a WebView, you don't need any webapp.

Comment: Your solution is good but that one is for Web based apps. I am developing an Native app, so i want solution related to display special characters in Native. anyways thanks for the answer..

Comment: A WebView is a part of a native app ;-) and can run locally without internet

Comment: That's true but as per my requirement i am have nearly 300 formulas, i need to convert each one in html & need to load using webview... It takes very long time na.........

Comment: So I guess you will have to write you own canvas.. I don't see any alternative.