# How to get value from mathematical formula writed by LaTeX type? use Java

Tags: java, latex

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6CXn.png)
How to  get value from mathematical formula writed by LaTeX type? use Java

I user MathLive write Mathematical formula, As shown in the picture.
Can I put [2^2\cdot2\cdot3] (writed by LaTeX ) to java, then get value from function.
put [2^2\cdot2\cdot3] to java, then get value 24 from function.

thank you very much.

Comment: Check this topic:
[full-latex-parser-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777558/full-latex-parser-in-java)