# Android: How to show the Special character or Alpha character keypad?

Tags: android, special-characters, android-edittext, android-keypad

I want to show the Special character keypad as soon as Edittext get the focus... Please help in this

And also tell me how to show Alpha character keypad as soon as Edittext get the focus..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: check this link     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698960/how-to-show-special-characters-in-android

Comment: I want to show the "Special character keypad" , not special characters

Comment: Hi ,  android:inputType="" dont have any thing related to particularly Special characters. but you have for numbers alone.

Comment: ok... now my problem is im using edittext.setInputType(1); this code for show alphanumeric keypad. But as soon as Edittext get focus, the keypad with special character only getting display, instead of showing with alpha

Comment: try to add the digits parameter to your editText:

android:digits="abcde.....012345789"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to show special character only keyboard. You can change the inputType property of EditText to change the keyboard type and play with it.. [These](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ainputType) are the available options. But none of those options give you a special character only keyboard.

```
<EditText 
 ......
 .......
 android:inputType="" //Play with it
 .......
 />
```

Comment: Actually my problem is now, as soon as Edittext get focus, the keypad is displaying with special character... but i want to show the alpha character first

Comment: which input type you used?

Comment: In any case, your only option with keyboard type is to play with input type. Just try it out with all possible options and see any of them fit your needs

Comment: i used alpha numeric keypad only, but as soon as Edittext get focus, keypad with special character only displaying

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get that kind of a keyBoard with any i/p text combination. You could create a custom keyboard for this. You could refer to this : [How to make a Android custom keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577304/how-to-make-a-android-custom-keyboard)